# Is it possible to create COM Component in C#.net?

Tags: c#, .net, com

Which type of project we take to create COM Component in Visual Studio?Can we implement IUnknown interface and its methods QueryInteface(),Addref() and Release() in C#

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create COM components in C# as Windows form, Library etc. You can also implement IUnknown. You need to set COM Visible to true in Project Properties.

Have look at [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/aa645736%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)